# Transforming a string to a slice indice and assign a value to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

Example:

```
sb = "Washington"
removecharsDB = [":2","-1:"]
```

What I want to do is to remove a part of `sb` using `removecharsDB`.

First thing I've did is to create a list of `sb`.

```
r = list(sb)
r
['W', 'a', 's', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 't', 'o', 'n']
```

Then

```
r[:2] = ""
r[-1:] = ""
"".join(r)
```

result: "shingto"

But I want to do it dynamically.

```
for n in removecharsDB:
   r[eval(n)] = ""

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

for n in removecharsDB:
    r + eval("[" + n + "]") = ""

SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

for n in removecharsDB:
    eval("r[" + n + "]") = ""

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

How can I transform a string to a slice indice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python eval and string indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359288/python-eval-and-string-indexing)

Comment: @CorentinPane, no, my problem is not to create the variable but to assign a value to the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the strings `":2"` and `"-1:"` to extract the start and stop of the slice. Note that an empty value in slice notation is the same as None.

As requested in your comment, if the string is `"3"`, we can generate the slice `[3:4]` to be replaced.

So, you can do:

```
sb = "Washington"
removecharsDB = [":2","-1:", "3"]

slices = [[int(val) if val else None for val in s.split(':')]
          if ':' in s else [int(s), int(s)+1 or None] for s in removecharsDB]
# print(slices)
# [[None, 2], [-1, None], [3, 4]]

r = list(sb)
for start, stop in slices:
    r[start:stop] = []

print("".join(r))
# shigto
```

Comment: +1 , because this is much better than the `eval()` method, since it is safe to work with invalid and potentially dangerous content of `removecharsDB`.

Comment: Thanks Thierry. It works fine but not if removecharsDB has digits as element p.e. `removecharsDB = ["0","2","-1:"]`

Comment: I updated the answer for the case of a single index.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you. What did I wrong in my example? Isn't it possible using eval()?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille. Just found out that there is still a problem when there are single negative values in removecharsDB. p.e. `removecharsDB = [":2", "-1"]`

Comment: `eval` can only evaluate expressions (like `x+1`), nothing more. You could have used `exec`: `exec("r[" + n + "] = []")` - but don't! ;)

Comment: @Reman Right, in case the one item long slice starts at -1, it should end at None, not 0. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With Pyhon's [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object:

```
s = "Washington"
s_lst = list(s)
removechars_lst = [":2","-1:"]

for sl in removechars_lst:
    s_lst[slice(*[int(i) if i else None for i in sl.split(':')])] = ''

print(''.join(s_lst))   # shingto
```

P.S. please follow Python *naming* conventions (`removecharsDB` is a bad sample).